# Due to a series of unrelated events Cocaine has been legalized. How does this affect society?

Tags: internal-consistency

Let me pitch you a setting: The year is 2018, and due to a series of unrelated events Cocaine has been legalized. How does this affect society and more importantly...

how does society react?

Note: Cocaine can now be bought in Pharmaceutical stores after this law had been passed.

P.S. Don't point out how unrealistic this question is. I am merely interested in how society (U.S.A.) reacts to such an asinine change.

Comment: "Society" is an amazingly broad topic. Questions that are along the lines of "It's Earth, but with this small changes. How does society diverge?" are overly broad and, thus, ill-suited to the Stack Exchange model.

Comment: It is NOT an asinine change, it's simple common sense.  Note that cocaine WAS legal for much of the US's history, with no significant problems.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that "jamesqf"! I don't have a strong grasp of History so thank you for telling me for that!

Comment: [Portugal legalized all drugs](https://www.google.com/search?q=country+legalized+all+drugs&oq=country+legalized&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.2972j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) 15 years ago, so you can check and see how they fared.

Answer (score 5):

Organised crime collapses. Prison populations crash. A bunch of rebellions are no longer able to fund themselves. Police have fewer reasons to randomly harass minorities. Addicts will be treated instead of criminalised.

Downsides? Can't really think of any.

Comment: Police have fewer reasons to randomly harass all of us, not just minorities.

Answer (score 3):

Cocaine, Nicotine, and Caffeine are very similar, they just differ in details and scale of effect.  How does this affect society?

Compare the prohibition of alcohol, and how the deregulation of alcohol partially broke up organized crime.  However, note, that Organized Crime didn't disappear, they just found a new market.

As for how it affects social interactions... I'd actually not expect much change.  It'd just join Caffeine and Nicotine as casual mood altering chemicals.

I'd also suggest you explore the concept of Cocaine being legalized... but Crack Cocaine being cracked down even harder.  This would have the effect of even more persecution of minorities and an enhancement of the Drug War problems we have today.  Right now, many, many non-minorities use cocaine even though it's illegal, firm in the knowledge they're going to get away with it.  Legalizing cocaine, but continuing criminalization of crack would give non-minorities even more ammunition to fuel the criminalization divide in our country:  why don't those poor people just buy the high quality high purity high-markup cocaine from the friendly neighborhood pharmacy right next to the police station like regular people...?

I think I've convinced myself it would cause more problems, actually, based on the knowledge that most drug laws have never been about protecting health (that's a side effect) but have usually been about boxing minorities into corners.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that this happens *just* for cocaine, and worldwide. I don't think the fictional setting will change much.

- Prices go down for cocaine. It will become available in standard purity.
- Some users may move from still illegal drugs to the now legal drug.
- Accidental overdoses become slightly less likely as people can buy standard purity. Infections through used needles, etc. go down.
- Organized crime peddles *other* drugs, plus their non-drug ventures. Some cartels which are heavily involved in the cocaine business take a hit, but they won't be taken out.
- There might be a slight increase in total drug use, as people who were previously unable to afford drugs (or scared by law enforcement) take the habit.

Consider that alcohol is legal in most places. There are people who abstain, others who control their occasional habit, yet others who are addicted. Giving them another choice won't change society in **significant** ways.

Legalizing cocaine in the US only would put significant pressure on the production and transit states as well, as there is no more DEA assistance and perhaps even lobbying for "free trade."

Answer (score 1):

It is obviously fairly difficult to predict but one large difference would be in the underworld of drug dealing. As with everything that is difficult to transport cocaine has a higher asking price whilst it is illegal. If legal it can be shipped or produced in huge amounts (and, as such, be cheaper to do so) rather than smuggling it in or having a small organization in the country. There would be more people producing it and giving the mafias and such competition...competition I'm sure they wouldn't approve of.

Sure maybe more people take it and that will effect their concentration, dependency perhaps ability to do their jobs. It may also increase the number of people seeking help for addictions to cocaine, the illegal aspect is what keeps a lot of them from rehab centers. Of course this depends on public opinion at the time and on why your hypothetical government legalizes Cocaine. Would they profit from promoting it in the public eye? [Here](http://www.gallup.com/poll/1657/illegal-drugs.aspx) is a bit of an overview of what people think at the moment.

The point, I think, is that we can try to speculate how our world would react but in order for it to be legalized something big has to happen. That big something, I'm guessing, is in your "series of unrelated events". Perhaps if you could explain a few of these we can help more, until then all I can offer is there would be quite a shift in power in the underworld as they struggle to keep their monopoly on supplying the cocaine.

Answer (score -3):

They aren't going to legalize cocaine, the only reason marijuana was legalized in some US states is because it isn't lethal or actually chemically addicting. In fact, the people who got it illegalized knew it wasn't bad, but they had to make something look bad so they wouldn't go bankrupt. Check this link for more info on that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJlqsdezhhk
As for what would happen if it WAS legalized? Death rates due to it would likely increase a lot.

Comment: This is worldbuilding... the request is to imagine a universe where cocaine IS legalized, and speculate on the consequences.

Comment: Why do you think death rates would increase? When it's legal it's far easier for people to seek professional medical help. Also, a main reason for cocaine deaths is the risk of buying cocaine mixed with other stuff. That becomes far less likely when cocaine is sold by official companies which can be made liable when their product isn't as pure as advertised on the box.

Comment: Also a large part of the reason people use cocaine (or other drugs) is because they are illegal, so there's the thrill of rebellion.  When they're legal, you can see how boring most of them really are.

Comment: @jamesqf, and how boring other people who are on them are.