# Due to a series of random events Insider Trading has been legalized, How is the Worldwide economy affected?

Tags: internal-consistency, economy

The Year is 2019, and thanks to a series of random events the act of Insider Trading has been legalized across the globe.

How is the Global Economy affected?

Do small companies/nations collapse due to this?

and more importantly... how does this affect the stock market?

Comment: all the problems with your [earlier post](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/66803/809) apply here as well. With most questions closed and net question score negative, you are on your way for automatic question ban now. Try to fix them. And remember, deleted questions are even worse than downvoted or closed when it comes to ban (or at least was worse, when I last checked).

Comment: but that post was about society. Which apparently is FAR too broad for this website. However this post is about the worldwide economy (and is even tagged under economy!). Sorry but I do not understand how all the problems with my earlier post apply to this post, (again, sorry about that)

Comment: If you are arguing with people explaining what they do not like with your posts, you are only encouraging them to downvote or close without a word. Fix your questions or don't but please, don't try to start an argument.

Comment: I am sorry if my earlier comment came off as rude. That was not my intention (Note: I do NOT want to start an argument as internet argument)

Comment: and could you please tell how I can fix my question(s)?

Comment: IMHO, your premise would be so completely market destroying that no government (or semi-self regulating market, like Wall Street) would even entertain the thought.  Simply infeasible as it would KILL all rational trading.

Comment: @Catalyst: Re insider trading being market destroying, you do realize that it was the norm throughout most of human history?  It only became illegal in the US since 1934.

Comment: like I said in one of my earlier questions. I am NOT well versed in history

Comment: I am amused that the stock market collapse is considered more important than the collapse of entire nations. #FirstWorldProblems! The question itself can be reduced to just "Why do we have insider trading laws?" See here: http://business.time.com/2013/07/26/why-is-insider-trading-even-illegal/ or here: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Why+is+insider+trading+illegal%3F ;-)

Comment: remember the Great Depression? that was caused by a stock market crash. So (theoretically) a stock market crash of a great enough magnitude COULD cause the collapse of society

Answer (score 2):

The answer is most likely that, by 2023 or so, insider trading is once again illegal.

Insider trading is forbidden because it makes it too easy for decision makers in companies to profit from information that others do not yet have.  The instant it becomes legal, you will start seeing executives doing it.  There's too many billions at stake not to.  The result will lead to a rapid growth of non-confidence in the stock market.  Investors will flee, seeing how executives simply trimmed all the fat off of investment.  There's enough questions regarding High Velocity Traders, who operate using information mere milliseconds earlier than others.  There just wouldn't be any return on investment with such a corrupt system.

In response, the only plausible solution would be to restore insider trading to its illegal status, or completely overhaul the entire global economy from the ground up in every way.  Nobody wants to do the latter, so I expect the former.

For a more in depth solution, you may want to look into what specific "random events" occurred.  They must have been pretty spectacular indeed for the market to do something as idiotic as this, so what they actually were will likely affect the outcome.  For example, if WWIII starts, and the executives convince everyone that the only way they can support the war is if they have enough control over their stocks and a side effect of that level of control is insider trading, those rules may subsist long after my estimated time.  In a war situation, prominent figures often choose to "do the right thing," even when they're not legally mandated to.  They might simply not engage in insider trading because there is a bigger issue at stake: the fate of the nation.  That will play out very differently than if we merely have some lobbyist who manages to get a law passed to line the purses of their employers.